# Declaração e inicialização de struct fora da função main em C

Tags: c, struct, variáveis

Estou fazendo um joguinho em C que possui a estrutura carta:

```
typedef struct {
    int numero;
    int cor;
} TipoCarta;
```

Um método para colocar os valores na carta:

```
void inicializaCarta(TipoCarta *carta, int num, int cor){
    carta->numero = num;
    carta->cor = cor;   
}
```

E na main eu terei que declarar e inicializar cada carta passando os valores, por exemplo:

```
TipoCarta amarelo1, amarelo2;
inicializaCarta(&amarelo1, 1, amarelo); 
inicializaCarta(&amarelo2, 2, amarelo);
```

(no cabeçalho tem uma constante definindo um inteiro para amarelo)

É possível fazer essa inicialização em outro arquivo .c, ou pelo menos fora da main? Pro código não ficar tão "poluído", visto que terá muitas cartas.

Comment: Parece ser possível, mas não sei se entendi a dúvida exata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o problema é a poluição, você poderia reescrever sua `main()` de uma outra forma, veja só:

```
typedef enum { corVermelho, corAzul, corVerde, corAmarelo } TipoCor;

typedef struct {
    int numero;
    TipoCor cor;
} TipoCarta;

void inicializaCarta( TipoCarta * carta, int num, TipoCor cor ){
    carta->numero = num;
    carta->cor = cor;
}

int main( void ) {
    int i = 0;

    TipoCarta amarelo[10];
    TipoCarta azul[10];
    TipoCarta verde[10];
    TipoCarta vermelho[10];

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        inicializaCarta( &vermelho[i], i + 1, corVermelho );
        inicializaCarta( &azul[i], i + 1, corAzul );
        inicializaCarta( &verde[i], i + 1, corVerde );
        inicializaCarta( &amarelo[i], i + 1, corAmarelo );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

No exemplo acima, `10` cartas de `4` cores diferentes foram inicializadas, totalizando `40` cartas.

Alternativamente, você pode colocar suas `Cartas` dentro de um `Deck`, veja só:

```
typedef enum { corVermelho, corAzul, corVerde, corAmarelo } TipoCor;

typedef struct {
    int numero;
    TipoCor cor;
} TipoCarta;

typedef struct {
    TipoCarta amarelo[10];
    TipoCarta azul[10];
    TipoCarta verde[10];
    TipoCarta vermelho[10];
} TipoDeck;

void inicializaCarta( TipoCarta * carta, int num, TipoCor cor ){
    carta->numero = num;
    carta->cor = cor;
}

void inicializaDeck( TipoDeck * deck )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        inicializaCarta( &deck->vermelho[i], i + 1, corVermelho );
        inicializaCarta( &deck->azul[i], i + 1, corAzul );
        inicializaCarta( &deck->verde[i], i + 1, corVerde );
        inicializaCarta( &deck->amarelo[i], i + 1, corAmarelo );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    TipoDeck deck;
    inicializaDeck( &deck );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: bem interessante, vou testar, obrigada :)